# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() localisation not working

Tags: ios, swift, localization, storekit

SKStoreReviewController is working based on device language, but my app consists a language button by which user can force change the app language but it is not reflecting on `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()`

with below code am changing the language of the app

```
UserDetails.shared.langauge = "en"
Bundle.setLanguage("en")


var langauge: String {
    get { return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "langauge") ?? "en" }
    set {
        if newValue == "en"{
            Bundle.setLanguage("en")
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        }else{
            Bundle.setLanguage("ar")
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "langauge")
    }
}
```